# Configure fails to detect proper ld on a 64-bit system with 32-bit userland

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, 32bit-64bit, autoconf

I have an i386 debian system running in an lxc container. The userland is 32 bit, the kernel is 64 bit. Thus configure detects this:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Probably this is taken from the output of *uname -m*

I have a package which builds fine with gcc and the result is a proper 32 bit binary. Unfortunately in another c++ project I get this:

```
configure:8595: checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries
```

From here on the linker is using this switch and thus will try to link 64 bit libs instead of 32 bit and it fails:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Though the library .so file is the proper 32 bit ELF:

```
file /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.*      
/usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.42.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

What's odd is that configure works fine for the other project and the linker is detected correctly to use the proper arch (elf_i386):

```
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_i386) supports shared libraries... yes
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

I just remove unknown for the syntax of command.
The problem is the target: `/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/`
An idea to reconfigure target in a conf flie?

This works for me:

Replace:
`./configure --host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
  --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --options...`

By:
`./configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --options...`

Answer (score 1):

> Probably this is taken from the output of uname -m

This configure script is clearly confused.

To un-confuse it, tell it *exactly* what you want it to do:

```
./configure --host=i686-unknown-linux-gnu --build=i686-unknown-linux-gnu \
  --target=i686-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Actually it looks like this case needs to be treated similar as a cross compilation. Using the above configure flags, I still have places where the build doesn't run the same as on a native 32 bit env. For example I have an #ifdef LINUX conditon in the code and this isn't satisfied even with the switches. In the c++ project configure is called from a complex Makefile so it is not that easy to tell it exactly what to do. And considering the #ifdef LINUX case there might be a couple other surprises. I decided it is easier and safer to go back to a native 32 bit vm.